# How to split a list and save objects individually?

Tags: r

I am trying to add a new column to multiple data frames, and then replace the original data frame with the new one. This is how I am creating the new data frames:

```
df1 <- data.frame(X1=c(1,2,3),X2=c(1,2,3))
df2 <- data.frame(X1=c(4,5,6),X2=c(4,5,6))

groups <- list(df1,df2)
groups <- lapply(groups,function(x) cbind(x,X3=x[,1]+x[,2]))
groups

[[1]]
  X1 X2 X3
1  1  1  2
2  2  2  4
3  3  3  6

[[2]]
  X1 X2 X3
1  4  4  8
2  5  5 10
3  6  6 12
```

I'm satisfied with how the new data frames have been created. What I'm stuck on is then breaking up my `groups` list and then saving the list elements back into their respective original data frames.

**Desired Output**

Essentially, I want to do something like `df1,df2 <- groups[[1]],groups[[2]]` but that is of course not syntatically valid. I have more than 2 data frames, which is why I'm hoping for a more programmatic approach than simply typing out N lines of code.

Comment: Keeping data.frames with the same structure in lists is usually a pretty good idea in R as you can use `lapply` and other tools to work with them. See gregor's answer on [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17499013/how-do-i-make-a-list-of-data-frames) for a number of useful tips. You can also add names to your list item to make them easier to access: `names(groups) <- c("df1", "df2")`.

Comment: Thank you, that's a very informative thread. I'll try to implement that approach. I am still curious about my original question, if anyone would still care to answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
for (i in 1:length(groups)){
   assign(paste("df",i,sep=""),as.data.frame(groups[[i]]))
}
```

should do it. Try it out, please.

Comment: Close.  It should be `for (i in 1:length(groups)){
     assign(paste0("df",i),as.data.frame(groups[[i]]))
}`

Comment: Thank you, your post was helpful in guiding me to my own answer. Your solution works when the data frames are sequentially numbered, but I will post an answer that will work for any naming conventions.

Answer (score 1):

@Rockbar led me to a general solution as well:

```
for(i in 1:length(groups)){
  assign(names(groups)[i],as.data.frame(groups[[i]]))
}

> df1
  X1 X2 X3
1  1  1  2
2  2  2  4
3  3  3  6
> df2
  x1 X3 X3
1  4  4  8
2  5  5 10
3  6  6 12
```

I should note that this only works if the objects in the list are all named. Thank you again @Rockbar for guiding me to this.